# JQuery Timepicker is not running in angualrjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, binding, timepicker

I have one application which was built under angular js and asp.net MVC.

Recently one change I have to make in that, I have to set time picker and get the values of selected time and store it in the database.

Binding is also done in a proper way but when I change the value it is not reflecting the ng-model which is bind to that particular text control.

How to solve this problem!!!

[time picker](http://timepicker.co/)

Comment: it's best to not use jQuery with angularjs, since it's not part of angular digest cycle. You would need to wrap it with `$timeout` or call `$scope.apply` as a hack. You can try search for similar libraries, but for angularjs. Those will use jQLite in directives

Comment: I highly recommend using the Angular [UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) directives for stuff like this.

Comment: @AlekseySolovey you are right sir I am really frustrate with those timeout and apply every time but I also don't know how to use directive and use angular side timepicker. Can you guide me a little bit.

Comment: @Lex Thank you I will look into that ..